# How to add custom (string based) bullet list into wagtail WYSIWYG

Tags: python-3.x, wysiwyg, wagtail, wagtail-admin, draftail

I am looking for a way to register a new editor feature to the wagtail WYSIWYG editor.

The following code adds the bullet list to the editor. (It is also built-in).

```py
@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_arrow_styling(features):
    """ Add the <arrow> to the ritch text editoe."""
    
    feature_name = "somename"
    type_ = "unordered-list-item"
    tag = "li"

    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'label': 'arrow',
        'description': 'list item',
    }

    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail',
        feature_name,
        draftail_features.BlockFeature(control)
    )

    db_conversion = {
        'from_database_format': {
                "ul": ListElementHandler(type_),
                tag: ListItemElementHandler(),
        },
        'to_database_format': {
            'block_map': {type_: {
                "element": tag,
                "wrapper": "ul",
                "props": {
                        "class": "li-arrow",
                    }
            }}
        },
    }

    features.register_converter_rule(
        'contentstate',
        feature_name,
        db_conversion
    )

    # This will register this feature with all editors by default
    features.default_features.append(feature_name)
```

What I need is to make the editor adds  based list points (say "-") instead of the regular bullet points, so I can style it as a text, e.g. change color.

The main goal actually is to get the freedom of changing the bullet points colors.

Thanks